# Hashtag Link System

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, hashtag

When I click the 'Learn More' button I would like to make the 'Third Link' button show as selected. Any solutions for this?

html

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">First Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Second Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Third Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Fourth Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Fifth Link</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li><a class="learnmore" href="#">Learn More</a></li>
</ul>
```

jquery

```
$('a').click( function() {
    $('a').not(this).removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q79PP/1/)

Comment: It is also not clear from your question what exactly you need. Do you need to know how to reference the "Third Link" element? Will it always be the 3rd in a set? Or do you want to be able to reference it wherever it appears? The [introductions on the jQuery site](http://learn.jquery.com/) might be useful to get you started.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm wanting to reference it wherever it appears. (e.g. when you click on the 'Learn More' button it will add the .selected class to the 'Third Link' button. I'm wanting to have more buttons around the page such as 'Sign up' than would add the .selected class to lets say 'First Link' button.

Comment: Ask a question about _how_ to do what you need to do, not asking somebody to do all the work for you. If you found out about jQuery selectors (by Class or ID, particularly) and tried creating another jQuery handler **just for the Learn More <a> tag**, you'd be well on your way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class to your third link so that you can help jQuery identify it.

```
<li><a href="#" class="third">Third Link</a></li>
```

Then instruct your code to add the `.selected` class to it if an anchor with the `.learnmore` class is clicked.

```
$('a').click( function() {
$('a').not(this).removeClass('selected');
$(this).addClass('selected');
// new code below
if ($(this).hasClass('learnmore')) {
    $('a.third').addClass('selected');
};
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/johntobinme/q79PP/2/)